# Picking numbers without picking neighbours

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can I choose 7 integers between 1 and 48, so that I never pick any neighbouring numbers (like 23 and 24)?
I am looking for a good way to attack this problem.
I have a strong feeling that the problem would become easier if I said that 1 and 48 were neighbours. I would get rid of boundary problems, when I count.
Using the inclusion-exclusion principle seems an idea, but I haven't found the right way.

Thx in advance, 
Jschmidt

Answer (score 4):

you can obtain a bijection between the sets of $k$ elements in the range $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ without neighbouring elements and the $k$ element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n-k+1\}$

The bijection is as follows:

If you have $\{a_1<a_2,\dots<a_k\}$ you map this to $\{a_1,a_2-1,a_3-2,\dots, a_k-k+1\}$

Answer (score 0):

A) One way to think of this is to line up 41 sticks (representing the numbers not chosen) in a row, and then $\;\;\;$choosing 7 of the resulting 42 gaps into which dots (representing the numbers chosen) can be placed.

B) Another way to do this is to let $x_i$ be the number of integers in gap $i$ in the 8 gaps created by the 7 integers $\;\;\;$chosen, so
$\;x_1+\cdots+x_8=41\;$ with $x_i\ge1$ for $2\le i\le 7$ and $x_1,x_8\ge0$.

$\hspace{.2 in}$Now count the number of solutions satisfying these conditions.